# How to make laser written waveguides?

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, experimental-technique, fiber-optics, photonics

I don't know if this is the right place to make such a question, but I have spent a few days trying to get a review or really informative article on how to make Photonic Integrated Circuits by laser engraving if anyone could recommend a paper or source I'd be really grateful

PD: I do not know a lot about experimental physics my area is Quantum optics however I'm interested in the design and production of simple chips for experiments, thanks in advance

Comment: One possible method for optical waveguides on a plane is to use a negative-acting photoresist: it will dissolve where it is *not* exposed to light.  The challenge is to choose a substrate that has a low refractive index.

Answer (score 0):

This paper came up in a google search, and seems to have references to a lot of different approaches to making waveguides by laser writing: "Femtosecond-laser-written Microstructured Waveguides in BK7 Glass".

In addition to the possibility I mentioned in a comment, you could try using positive resist to make trenches in a layer, then fill the trenches with a high-index resin.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definetely read it , seems very instructice